# How to create shortcut to System Settings in Windows 10 Power Options?

Tags: windows-10

How can I create a shortcut to Laptop Lid Open/Close power setting?

[image]

at control panel to land at following page

[image]

I added this to

Desktop-> New Shortcut ->

[image]

Comment: try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) as this question is not related to programming. thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a shortcut to the Power Options Global Settings use this location:

```
control /name Microsoft.PowerOptions /page pageGlobalSettings
```